# Trying to Decipher Pin Function of A EM Relay (Data Sheet Included)

Tags: relay, datasheet

Thank you for reading this.

Goal: to understand the functions of pins of EC2-3NU, a single coil non-latching electromechanical relay.

Data sheet: https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_R7002_EC2_EE2.pdf

Relevant portion: 
[image]
Note: I could not find anything else regarding pin functions for the intended model in the data sheet.

My understanding: From the picture, it seems that pin 4 and 9 are the "common" pins, pins 5 and 8 are the "normally open" pins, and pins 3 and 10 are the "normally closed" pins. If so, then why do we have two of each pin? Is this relay capable of controlling 2 separate outputs?

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

That is a double pole (DPDT) relay - it can switch two separate circuits, same as a DPDT toggle switch.

I would expect a datasheet to say "DPDT" or similar on the first page, but this one expects you to determine that from the circuit drawing you found, or to see "Two form C" on the contact specification table on page 7.  (A "form C" switch contact is a single pole double throw (SPDT) switch).

Comment: Got it, thank you!